# MYSQL Window functions

Tags: mysql, rank

order has multiple order_status before it is finally delivered to customer. Sometimes customer places multiple orders from different sources. We accept one order but we reject the other order. I want to find out what was the latest order status of accepted order when the duplicate order was cancelled.

```
LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT order_id AS order_id,order_status,max(addtime(`timestamp`,'05:30:00')) AS timestamp
            FROM pe2.order_history
            GROUP BY 1,2
) oh ON oh.order_id = ord.order_id AND oh.timestamp <= c.time. 
c.time. is duplicate order cancellation time.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the desired customer's order, then we get the latest status for the same order, which is before the cancellation of the duplicate order:

```
SELECT order.*,
(SELECT order_status FROM order_history AS oh 
WHERE order_id = order.id AND timestamp <= cancel_time
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_status
FROM order
WHERE order.ID = accepted_order
```